# Can't get object-position to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something very simple: a static background and an centralized image that scrolls over it.
It has to be all inline styling, as the place where I wanna put it only accepts the tags a p i strong b u ul ol li h1 h2 h3 img font br span.

My little code is currently like this:

```
<p style="background:url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ba/d4/6a/bad46a1f4e0259ea2ba5319318a74714.jpg); 
width:2000px; 
height:auto; 
left:0px; 
top:0px;  
z-index:-100;

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: bottom;">

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/2QwvWCt.png" style="
width: 700px;
height: auto;
object-position: center top;
z-index:1;"/>

</p>
```

But the presence or absence of "object-position: center top;" seems to have no effect over the image at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

[`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) refers to the position of the element in relation to **its own box**, not within a containing parent.

So we have an image that is naturally *smaller* than its designated size, *then* the object position comes into play.

For instance, set a 300px image to be 500px wide and `object-fit: none;` and you get...

```css
img {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  object-position: top center;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  object-fit: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://baconmockup.com/300/200" />
```

> The object-position CSS property specifies the alignment of the selected replaced element's contents within the element's box. Areas of the box which aren't covered by the replaced element's object will show the element's background.
>
> You can adjust how the replaced element's object's intrinsic size (that is, its natural size) is adjusted to fit within the element's box using the object-fit property.

Comment: Ooooh I get it now. This was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p style="background:url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ba/d4/6a/bad46a1f4e0259ea2ba5319318a74714.jpg); 

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: bottom;
text-align: center;">

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/2QwvWCt.png" style="
width: 700px;
height: auto;"/>

</p>
```

Comment: It's a very strange case. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think that was almost it... For some weird reason it makes the image go to a center that is not exactly the center of the background, but of the page, which apparently exceeds the background size. I don't know if that makes sense the way I explained it. But at least now I can effectively move the image around, thank you!